# Fetch API with NO-CORS redirect - can't get any Response Headers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch-api

I have gone over a dozen pages, explanations, questions here, and I am kinda getting frustrated. Noone talks of this situation directly.. So here's what I have... My torrent tracker http://www.tribalmixes.com/ has a script that scans my radio https://www.tm-radio.com/ for new episodes that aired today and shares those as torrents. this game has been happening since 2006. The script checks response headers of some pages and decides whether to download as mp3 or skip in case of the html response.

So recently i've switched radio to https and now there's a 301 redirect in the chain of request-response. I understand there are other solutions to this, but i decided to try fetch API first.. Back in 2006-2007 i was really proud to have remade my torrent tracker with AJAX, only thanks to that lost proper search engine indexing and bunch of users didn;t like it.. Anyways, now am trying to use fresh new technologies on the remade radio site. And since AJAX is not that fancy anymore, going with Fetch API. so once again, I am trying to replace AJAX with FETCH on an already existing mechanism without remaking the mechanism.

But sites are obviously different, so I have to do NO-CORS request, since script is on tribalmixes.com. although sites are on same server. so of course simple folder check can work, but trying to look into the future when sites are separated. Another solutions would be to run a simple ajax request to a local php script that would CURL the URL and return the headers. But why not Fetch? =)

so here's what I have so far for JS

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
var myInit = { method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: 'no-cors',
  redirect: 'follow',
  cache: 'default' };
fetch(turl, myInit).then(function(response) {
  const rtype = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
  console.log(rtype);
  for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
  }
  return (response);
}).then(function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});         
//for obvious reasons i am not posting the url..
```

the response I am getting is there but pretty much empty. No error. But for some reason "redirected" says "false"... i thought opaque only shows when NO-CORS redirect happens, no?

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
  __proto__: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response
}
```

So my question is: am I correct to assume that this is the right way to do it, and that this is undoable this way? Can or can not Fetch API deliver response headers on an opaque response. TBH all i get is that - response is opaque. everything else is empty... Everyone says they get at least something, but i just want 1 *none-guarded* header **Content Type**, and cannot get it no matter what i do... Is it NOT possible at the moment? this was all working towards an awesome mp3 converter like [keepvid](https://keepvid.works/).. but never went past the development stage,,

And before I go ahead and add other headers to radio server response, all i want is to see 1 simple header..

Please, help! losing my mind over here...

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question but Are you getting a CORS error or a pure redirect

Comment: added response I am getting. there is no error, and seems like redirect happens fine, but no indication of anything except opaque response type

Comment: no-cors lets fetch() retrieve a cross-origin resource, it doesn't however let you read the content as that would be a security issue.

Comment: i don't need the response yet, i just want to see the headers. I have read that none-guarded headers should be accessible, thus all this hell-raising.. was that info incorrect? or maybe i misunderstood?

Comment: whatwg spec specifies [opaque filtered response](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque) as having an empty header list.

Comment: so it is NOT possible, thank you, i will go the php+curl way then..

Comment: Yeah, to be clear, as far the requirements of CORS protocol goes, the headers are as much an integral part of the response as the response body is — and specifying `mode: 'no-cors'` tells the browser to block your frontend JavaScript code from any access to any part of the response, including all the response headers.